# iphone and iPod emulators

Tags: iphone, emulation, ipod

is there separate emulator for iPhone and iPod...?

in my computer i already installed iPhone emulator, can i install ipod emulator too with out losing iPhone simulator ?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one simulator for both. The iPhone is a superset of an iPod, so the iPhone simulator should meet all your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the *iPod*, development for the iPod is not included in the iPhone SDK.

If you mean the *iPod touch*, then the simulator is the same as the iPhone simulator.

-t